# Check if time is not conflict between time in array

Tags: php

I want to check if time (H:i) start - end is not conflict with times in array.
So I retrieved data from table reservation, and converted as into array:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'start' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 10:30'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 13:30'),
        'executor' => 1 //team 1
    ),
    array(
        'start' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 09:30'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 10:30'),
        'executor' => 2 //team 2
    ),
    array(
        'start' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 12:30'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 15:30'),
        'executor' => 2 //team 2
    ),
    array(
        'start' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 13:00'),
        'end' => new DateTime('2017-05-06 16:30'),
        'executor' => 2 //team 2
    )
);
```

Let's say, there's new visitor 1 try to do reservation, he input date:
If the date visitor input is collapsed with the one of data from table, so System must give him a warning "Your selected hour is not available". If nothing's collapsed so it will continue the process.

Case 1, visitor input this hour in reservation.

```
$start = new DateTime('2017-05-06 11:00');
$end = new DateTime('2017-05-06 14:00');
```

It should give warning out, because 11:00-14:00 is collapsed with data in array.

Case 2, visitor input this hour in reservation.

```
$start = new DateTime('2017-05-06 11:00');
$end = new DateTime('2017-05-06 13:00');
```

It gives warning out, as I expected.

My problem is case 1, why it doesn't give warning out?

Here we go the codes I use to do the check.

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (isBetween($start1, $end1, $row['start'], $row['end'])) {
        echo 'Your selected hour is not available';
    }
}



 function isBetween(DateTime $to_check_start, DateTime $to_check_end, DateTime $start, DateTime $end) {
        return ($to_check_start->format('H:i') >= $start->format('H:i') && $to_check_end->format('H:i') <= $end->format('H:i'));
    }
```

I need your advice, thank you.

Comment: @can u explain the question bit clearly..??

Comment: Comparing __strings__ always leads to unexpected results.

Comment: Sorry guys I was in hurry. I've update my question. thank you.